# $f_x$ is continuous, $f_{xt}$ is differentiable, does that mean $f_t$ is continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,t)$ be a function of space ($\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, a bounded set) and time (interval $[0,T]$).

Suppose $f_{x}$ is continuous wrt. $x$, and $f_{xt}$ (that's differential of $x$ first and then $t$) is differentiable wrt. $t$. Does this mean that $f_t$ exists? If so is it also continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(t,x)=|t|$. Now $f_x=0$, $f_{xt}=0$, but $f_t$ is undefined at $t=0$.